# jQuery toggleClass on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, toggleclass

I'm trying to change color to a header when it reaches a certain scroll. I use this script with jQuery:

```
var $document = jQuery(document),
    $element = jQuery('#header'),
    className = 'red';

$document.scroll(function() {
    $element.toggleClass(className, $document.scrollTop() >= 400);
});
```

That works on every browser, except for IE8. Does IE8 does not support the toggleClass? How can I solve it?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/itzuki87/e4XTw/

in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/itzuki87/e4XTw/show/

Comment: The problem is more likely to be with `.scrollTop()` than with `.toggleClass()`.

Comment: why are you mixing `$` and `jQuery` and what error do you get?

Comment: No errors, simply it doesn't change color.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the "scroll" event fires at all?

Comment: I cant even see a blank fiddle page in IE8 ... what shiv or polyfill have you tried?

Comment: @j08691 what do you mean with mixing `$` and `jQuery`. I only see that all jQuery result sets are prefixed with a `$` which is not an uncommon practice to show directly in source that it is a jQuery result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is [`$(document)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is read different in IE.  IE prefers you to use [`$(window)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You'll find the following to be much more cross-browser compatible.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        $("#header").toggleClass("red", $(this).scrollTop() >= 400);
    });
})
```

Or using your variable type setup:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var $window = jQuery(window),
        $element = jQuery("#header"),
        className = "red";

    $window.scroll(function(e) {
        $element.toggleClass(className, jQuery(this).scrollTop() >= 400);
    });
})
```

## See working in IE8! <sub><sub>and more (Safari, FF, Chrome, Opera)</sub></sub>!

---

### Using my <sub>smaller</sub> HTML

Comment: Thank you, you resolved! I didn't know of this problem with $document on IE, I thought it was a toggleClass problem because I found several questions on this on the net and I had focused on this. You never stop learning, thank you!